# Copy only modified and new files from source to destination in nant script

Tags: nant

Currently we are using copy command to copy files from one location to other, but it is coping all files over and again. Here I want to copy only modified and new files from source to destination.

Can any one please help me in this?

Here is sample code:

```
<copy overwrite="true" todir="destination">
      <fileset basedir="source">
        <include name="**/*"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would copy only modified files from source folder to destination folder:

```
<exec program="C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe" failonerror="false" >
  <arg line="${source} ${destination} /D /E /C /Q /H /R /Y /K" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks Nilay, it's working. But now i want to exclude few sub folders from source how to do that?